# How to automatically split table with princeXML

Tags: java, html, pdf, princexml

I have an HTML file that content an html table with many columuns (30) that I want to convert in PDF using the Software PrinceXML. 
Problem is my the table is too large and the end of the table and is out of the margin.
I have tried to use the property prince-shrink-to-fit: auto but the output is too small. 
What I want is to split the table and continue to the next page.
Is it possible?

Thanks you

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You could maybe increase page size. Just make it a really wide page?

Answer (score 0):

looks like a problem at official PrinceXML forum http://www.princexml.com/forum/topic/2224/big-large-tables